# How to return green user name now it is white

Tags: command-line

[this is pic of how my terminal looks now. I want to know to fix it. Does somebody know it before was green, but know it white.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBKV2.png)

My question is why now in terminal user is white color. Before is was green and there was no problem with access to the remote server now it ask for a password

[Update Also add on photo where u can see changes from different person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEjMp.png)

Comment: You either changed the color settings for your terminal emulator (see [here](https://itsfoss.com/change-terminal-color-ubuntu/) for the default GNOME terminal), or you changed your PS1 variable in your `.bashrc` or similar start up file. No way for us to know which. This has nothing to do with your problem logging in to the server. I have no idea how you could possibly expect anyone to diagnose that with no information provided whatsoever.

Comment: may be you have changed the terminal theme

Comment: Sorry guys, that i dont clearify question, before when i cant to connect server I just type ssh user@8.8.8.8 and its connect to the remove server, but it also ask password, also about color, if i switch user it becomes green.

Comment: Thanks you! It works